# ASP.NET Core 2.0 unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts Azure Web

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm currently working on a platform that connects to an external MySQL database. The problem comes when I try to connect to the database from the Azure web app. I never had this issue from my computer, so I'm wondering if Azure is the problem. I get a random unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts every 30 minutes.

I'm using the asp.net core MySQL driver with dapper to query the database.

```
public class MySqlContext : IMySqlContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public FrigoAppContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _connectionString = configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
    }

    public MySqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new MySqlConnection(_connectionString);
    }
}


public class FacturasVentaService : IFacturasVenta
    {
        private readonly IMySqlContext _context;

        public FacturasVentaService(IMySqlContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IQueryable<FacturaVenta> GetAll()
        {
            using (var connection = _context.GetConnection())
            {
                var query = @"SELECT id Id, idpedido IdPedido, idromaneio IdRomaneio,
                        data_emissao DataEmissao, cliente Cliente, vendedor Vendedor, 
                        documento Documento, documento_remessa DocumentoRemessa, observacao Observacion,
                        transportadora Transportadora, motorista Motorista, placa_frete_terrestre PlacaFreteTerrestre,
                        excluido Excluido, data_entregado DataEntregado, ruc Ruc, timbrado Timbrado, endereco Direccion,
                        sigla_moeda SiglaMoneda, idfilial IdFilial, entregado Entregado, data_vencimento DataVencimiento FROM faturamento_venda";
                return connection.Query<FacturaVenta>(query).AsQueryable();
            }
        }

        public IQueryable<FacturaVenta> GetWhere(string where, object param = null)
        {
            using (var connection = _context.GetConnection())
            {
                var query = @"SELECT id Id, idpedido IdPedido, idromaneio IdRomaneio,
                        data_emissao DataEmissao, cliente Cliente, vendedor Vendedor, 
                        documento Documento, documento_remessa DocumentoRemessa, observacao Observacion,
                        transportadora Transportadora, motorista Motorista, placa_frete_terrestre PlacaFreteTerrestre,
                        excluido Excluido, data_entregado DataEntregado, ruc Ruc, timbrado Timbrado, endereco Direccion,
                        sigla_moeda SiglaMoneda, idfilial IdFilial, entregado Entregado, data_vencimento DataVencimiento FROM faturamento_venda WHERE " + where;
                return connection.Query<FacturaVenta>(query, param).AsQueryable();
            }
        }

        public FacturaVenta GetById(int id)
        {
            using (var connection = _context.GetConnection())
            {
                var query = @"SELECT id Id, idpedido IdPedido, idromaneio IdRomaneio,
                        data_emissao DataEmissao, cliente Cliente, vendedor Vendedor, 
                        documento Documento, documento_remessa DocumentoRemessa, observacao Observacion,
                        transportadora Transportadora, motorista Motorista, placa_frete_terrestre PlacaFreteTerrestre,
                        excluido Excluido, data_entregado DataEntregado, ruc Ruc, timbrado Timbrado, endereco Direccion,
                        sigla_moeda SiglaMoneda, idfilial IdFilial, entregado Entregado, data_vencimento DataVencimiento FROM faturamento_venda WHERE id = @Id;";
                return connection.Query<FacturaVenta>(query, new { Id = id }).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }

        public int Insert(FacturaVenta factura)
        {
            using (var connection = _context.GetConnection())
            {
                var query = @"INSERT INTO faturamento_venda(idpedido, 
                        idromaneio, data_emissao, cliente, vendedor,
                        documento, documento_remessa DocumentoRemessa, observacao, 
                        transportadora, motorista, placa_frete_terrestre,
                        excluido, data_entregado) VALUES(@IdPedido, @IdRomaneio, @DataEmissao, @Cliente, @Vendedor,
                        @Documento, @DocumentoRemessa, @Observacao, @Transportadora, @Motorista, @PlacaFreteTerrestre, @Excluido, @DataEntregado)";
                return connection.Execute(query, factura);
            }
        }

        public bool Update(FacturaVenta factura)
        {
            using (var connection = _context.GetConnection())
            {
                var query = @"UPDATE faturamento_venda SET idpedido=@IdPedido, 
                        idromaneio=@IdRomaneio, data_emissao=@DataEmissao, cliente=@Cliente, vendedor=@Vendedor,
                        documento=@Documento, documento_remessa=@DocumentoRemessa, observacao=@Observacao, 
                        transportadora=@Transportadora, motorista=@Motorista, placa_frete_terrestre=@PlacaFreteTerrestre,
                        excluido=@Excluido, data_entregado=@DataEntregado;";
                return connection.Execute(query, factura) > 0;
            }
           
        }

        public bool Delete(FacturaVenta factura)
        {
            using (var connection = _context.GetConnection())
            {
                return connection.Execute("DELETE FROM faturamento_venda WHERE id = @Id", new { factura.Id }) > 0;
            }
        }

        public void Create(FacturaVenta factura)
        {
            
        }

        public int Execute(string query, object param)
        {
            using (var connection = _context.GetConnection())
            {
                return connection.Execute(query, param);
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything is inject in a transient scope.

I'm using MySql.Data 8.0.11 and Dapper 1.50.4

Other questions on Stack Overflow point to an error in the connection string such as IP, password, database name or port, but that is imposible since I sometimes can connect and sometimes not.

Comment: Use SQL Database on azure, there is a firewall (ip filter).  Not present with mysql?

Comment: According to your description, it seems that your webapp doesn't enable ''Always on ". Have you tried to enable ["Always on"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#application-settings) for Azure website?

Comment: What is the full exception message (with call stack and any inner exceptions)? Please read the instructions at http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/ on how to obtain this information and add it (as text) to your question.